# Textmate Regex (replace xml node and value)

Tags: xml, textmate

I have an XML data file with some irrelevant information. I want to use textmate to replace some of those nodes e.g. `GUID=''`and `ZIPcode=''`. Now these nodes have values within them which is different for each parent node.

e.g. XML FILE:

```
<parent>
   <customer firstName='blah' GUID='2131231j2n3123kj12n3123jkn' ZIPcode='r232 1232'>
   <customer firstName='superblah' GUID='asdasd12312312312312312' ZIPcode='213213'>
   <customer firstName='supersuperBlah' GUID='afasfasf213goi123io123123' ZIPcode='1232'>
</parent>
```

I am trying to use replace some of the nodes with different values within the parent node using regex. Is that possible?

Example of what i want to achieve:

FIND: `GUID='(*any value*)'`

REPLACE: (empty)

thanks in advance

Comment: What does "any value" mean? Can the GUID contain single-quotes? Only digits and lowercase letters?

Comment: And each value is really surrounded by *single* quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the GUID from each tag, find

```
\bGUID='[^']+'<PUT_A_SPACE_HERE>
```

and replace it with nothing.

Comment: doesnt work. What i want to do is delete every GUID element within the XML document. The only problem is that there are different values in each and every GUID node. Can i not replace all the GUID with different values with nothing.

Comment: Please add as much information to your question as possible, so we can better help you. It would be most helpful to see a demo input file, and then what you expect it to look like at the end. Then maybe I can give it another go. So far I don't understand.

Comment: Updated my answer. Better?